# modify all outbound links

Tags: javascript, html, append

I would like to modify all outbound links in a web page. I just want to append a dynamic string at the end of every URL. I use fetch to get this string. So far I'm able to fetch and modify the URL but I'm unable to append the fetched string.

**My Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Website</title>
<script>
fetch('https://httpbin.org/encoding/utf8')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then((text) => {
    document.getElementById("MyFetchedString").innerHTML = text.slice(0, 10);
      });
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", modify_outbound_links);

function modify_outbound_links(){
    anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        let p = anchors[i].href;
        if (p.indexOf('example.com') === -1) {
        //How do i append the fetchedText? 
            anchors[i].href = p + (p.indexOf('?') != -1 ? "&" : "?") + 'FetchedText'; 
        }
    }
} </script>
  </head>

<body>

  <h2>My First Web Page</h2>
  <p>My First Paragraph.</p>

  Modify all outbound links.<br>

 <p><a href="https://google.com/">Google.com</a></p>
<p><a href="https://yahoo.com/">Yahoo.com</a></p>
<p><a href="https://example.com/">mydomain.com</a></p>

<p id="MyFetchedString"></p>

</body>
```

Please help me append the received string to every outbound URL. My Main challenge is **this JavaScript line:** anchors[i].href = p + (p.indexOf('?') != -1 ? "&" : "?") + '**FetchedText** How do I append it here?';

Comment: Your code works fine.

Comment: can you elaborate more about what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hello @mamounothman, I  have edited the question. Kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like this, I noticed your removed the old link from the API but I put it back incase you need it to work with the code.

```js
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", modify_outbound_links);

function modify_outbound_links(){

  fetch('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?symbols=USD,GBP')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((json) => {

     anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        let p = anchors[i].href;
        if (p.indexOf('example.com') === -1) {
        //How do i append the fetchedText? 
            anchors[i].href = p + (p.indexOf('?') != -1 ? "&" : "?") + 'FetchedText&' + 'USD='+json['rates']['USD'] + '&GBP=' + json['rates']['GBP']; 
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("MyFetchedString").innerHTML = text.slice(0, 10);
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Website</title>
<script>
 </script>
  </head>
<body>

  <h2>My First Web Page</h2>
  <p>My First Paragraph.</p>
  Modify all outbound links.<br>

 <p><a href="https://google.com/">Google.com</a></p>
<p><a href="https://yahoo.com/">Yahoo.com</a></p>
<p><a href="https://example.com/">mydomain.com</a></p>

<p id="MyFetchedString"></p>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mamounothman. The code works perfectly with json data but I want to fetch the content as **text**.  Kindly help me achieve that.

Comment: I want to fetch the content as text

Comment: @gilbaO Sorry didn't notice your previous comment, will check it and get back to you.

Comment: What would **FetchedText** represent, can you give and example of `<a>` tag and how to it should look like?

Comment: The **FetchetText** is a string like "1234abc". It is a text.slice (8 characters) received from fetching  "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?symbols=USD,GBP"

Comment: @gilbaO Can you give a real sample of how it should look like, give me a URL composed from the json response you gave in your comment. sorry for not being able to understand your question :)

Comment: The link should look like this "https://google.com/?unicod"
"?" having been added and "unicod" being the string received from fetching https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?symbols=USD,GBP 
I hope you get me now.